# Laravel 5.5 file upload request->hasFile returns null

Tags: php, forms, laravel, file, laravel-5.5

I've been searching for a solution for hours. Tried putting enctype as most have suggested but still no solution.

HTML

```
        <form action="/backportal/knowledge/postlist" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" name="title">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Short Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Short description" name="short_desc">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Long Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Short description" name="long_desc">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Image</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image">
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Controller

```
    public function postlist(Request $request){
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        echo 'yes';
    }else{
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```

Comment: Its in the title

Comment: In you php settings is file uploads enabled: ```file_uploads = On```. What platform are you using?

Comment: hasFile is not only completely valid in 5.5 but also relevant to the OP's follow-on question since it would appear from the documentation that $request->file should return a file object any time hasFile returns true.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.5 you should be using [file](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#files):

```
public function postlist(Request $request){
    if ($request->file('image')) {
        echo 'yes';
    }else{
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that worked. However, now when I try to write the file, its an empty image.

Comment: you've just completely changed the contents of the question by updating it with my answer. not cool bro. You should've asked another question to another issue...